# Discord bot crashes when i try to add an image to embed with an if statement

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm making a message logger, this is the code:

```
client.on('messageDelete', (messageDelete) => {

const deletedContent = `${messageDelete.content}`
const attachment = messageDelete.attachments.first()

        const deletionEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('RANDOM')
            .setAuthor(`A message was deleted, content here:`)
            .setDescription(deletedContent)
            .addFields(

                { name: "Server:", value: `${messageDelete.guild.name}` },
                { name: "Channel:", value: `#${messageDelete.channel.name}` },
                { name: "Deleted by:", value: `${messageDelete.author.username}`},

            )
            .setTimestamp()

        if (messageDelete.attachments.size !== 0) {
            deletionEmbed.setImage(`${attachment.url}`)
        } 

        client.channels.fetch("875333721492975646").then((channel) => {
            channel.send(deletionEmbed).catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
            })
        })
});
```

The line `if (messageDelete.attachments.size !== 0) { deletionEmbed.setImage(attachment.url) }`  should add an image to the embed if there's any in the deleted message, and it does, but right after it crashes giving a `RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.` error, i don't why it happens, i already made different embeds that change based on situation and nothing went ever wrong. I also tried using a try/catch or console.error but they didn't resolve the problem and the bot kept crashing.

**EDIT**:
I've tried logging attachment.url and it does give the url, however when i click it it says this: `<Error> <Code>AccessDenied</Code> <Message>Access denied.</Message> <Details> Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object. </Details> </Error>` Also attachment has an other property called "proxyURL" among with the normal url, i also tried using that one but still nothing, even if the link works correctly

Comment: Does `attachment.url` have a non-empty value? You could try to log that

Comment: i edited the question and added what attachment.url logs

Answer (score 0):

You can always try the `? :` way.

basically, we gonna check if there is an attachment, if yes then we gonna put the attachment url, else we will set the image as null so it doesn't even show.

**Example:**

```js
const attachment = messageDelete.attachments.first()

const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('test')
.setImage(attachment ? attachment.url : null)
```

If that didn't work, please `console.log(attachment.url)` and let me know what does it log, else if my method works, enjoy your day!

Comment: So your method worked, but it still crashes, logging attachment.url gives the link as it should, but the link doesn't work and displays this error: `<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access denied.</Message>
<Details>
Anonymous caller does not have storage.objects.get access to the Google Cloud Storage object.
</Details>
</Error>`
Also attachment has an other property called "proxyURL" among with the normal url, i also tried using that one but still nothing, even if the link works correctly